# How do I ask / inform my supervisor that I need to take a day off?

Tags: etiquette, email, research-assistantship, working-time

I just recently got a job as a research assistant over the holiday (which will later turn into an unpaid independent study project). Before hiring me for the job, my supervisor asked me if I would be taking a week off for vacation during the holidays. I told him no. However, for Christmas, I recieved (as a gift) tickets for an afternoon weekday show of an expensive stage production. The show is about an hour and a half from where I live so I would need to take most of the day off. I will be informing my supervisor via email about this. How do I inform him/phrase the email?

Comment: "Hi Alice/Bob, can I take a day off on <day>?"

Answer (score 4):

XX,

I was just given a surprise gift -- tickets to a show in YY City.  It would be thrilling to go -- any chance you could spare me on Thursday?  Because of the distance, it would mean missing the whole day.  However, I'm free all day Saturday.  If you like, I could come in then to make up the time.

(however you like to sign your name)

*Please feel free to adjust this as needed.  For example, you can make the tone less breezy and more formal if you want to.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer for your question. It totally depends what kind of relationship you have with your supervisor. In my case I have very friendly relationship with supervisor and a text message is enough to inform him about this kind of minor issues.

Comment: My guess is that if it were that simple for the OP, s/he wouldn't have asked.... // Glad you hear you have this level of comfort with your advisor!